# Indexing a mapped type with keys of the original type

Tags: typescript

I'm working on a function that parses a CSV and returns an array of typed objects. That looks something like this.

```
type KeyToTransformerLookup<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends string ? never : K]: (
    stringValue: string
  ) => T[K];
};

export default function csvToArray<T>(
  csv: string,
  keys: Array<keyof T>,
  keyToTransformerLookup: KeyToTransformerLookup<T>,
  ignoreFirstLine = false
): T[] {
  const rows = csv.split(/\n(?=.)/);

  if (ignoreFirstLine) {
    rows.shift();
  }

  return rows.map((row) => {
    const values = row.split(/(?!\B"[^"]*),(?![^"]*"\B)/g);

    const rowObject: Record<any, any> = {};

    keys.forEach((key, index) => {
      const stringValue = values[index];

      if (key in keyToTransformerLookup) {
        rowObject[key] = keyToTransformerLookup[key](stringValue); // TypeScript complains
        return;
      }

      rowObject[key] = stringValue;
    });

    return rowObject as T;
  });
}
```

```
Type 'keyof T' cannot be used to index type 'KeyToTransformerLookup<T>'.
```

I would guess this is because once you map `K in keyof T` the resulting type is no longer even a partial of `keyof T` but something totally new. This is a bit frustrating since I am not transforming the keys, and I am also checking to see if `key` exists on `keyToTransformerLookup` anyways, so I would just like to find a way to index `keyToTransformerLookup` in a way that satisfies TypeScript.

Comment: TypeScript can't currently narrow the type of `k` by an `if (k in o)` check; see relevant feature request at [ms/TS#43284](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284).  For now, either you'd need to assert `k as keyof typeof o` or write a type guard function that works that way if you're going to do it multiple times: see [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/wgaL6m).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think so! I ended up just asserting the key as the correct type. [Link](https://github.com/Fimbelowski/ebird-api-ui/blob/main/src/utilities/csvToArray.ts)

Followup question; since `keyToTransformerLookup` is an object with all non-string members of `T`, is there a reasonable way to have the argument be optional if `T` has no non-string members?

Comment: I’ll write up an answer when I get a chance. … uh, followup questions are out of scope and technically should be presented in a new question post. I’m away from my computer right now so I can’t look at it, but I hope it’s not a prerequisite for answering.

Comment: Nope, not a prerequisite! Maybe in the future I will post about it but for now I'm sick of looking at this function. :)

Comment: Maybe [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WPKjem) is what you want, but I'd probably just add an overload.  Anyway this is off topic so I'll leave it alone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TypeScript's support for [narrowing via the `in` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#the-in-operator-narrowing) (also see [TS4.9 update to this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#unlisted-property-narrowing-with-the-in-operator)) currently only affects the apparent type of the *object* being checked, not the *key*.  That is, `if (k in o) {⋯} else {⋯}` only implies things for `o` and not for `k`.  There is an open feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#43284](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284) to add support for narrowing `k` also, but it's not implemented yet (as of TS5.0) and [it might be tricky to implement to everyone's satisfaction](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/43284#issuecomment-841748155).

So when you check `key in keyToTransformerLookup`, the type of `key` stubbornly stays `keyof T` and cannot be narrowed to `keyof KeyToTransformerLookup<T>`.

---

Until and unless TypeScript adds support for the kind of narrowing you're trying to do, you'll have to work around it.  The easiest workaround for a one-off check is to just [assert](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) that the type has been narrowed:

```
if (key in keyToTransformerLookup) {
  rowObject[key] = keyToTransformerLookup[
    key as keyof KeyToTransformerLookup<T>
  ](stringValue);
  return;
}
```

If you find yourself performing this kind of check a lot, you could write a [custom type guard function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/narrowing.html#using-type-predicates) for it:

```
function isKeyof<T extends object>(
  k: PropertyKey, o: T): k is keyof T {
  return k in o;
}
```

and then use it:

```
if (isKeyof(key, keyToTransformerLookup)) {
  rowObject[key] = keyToTransformerLookup[key](stringValue);
  return;
}
```

---

Note that it is *technically* unsafe to do such narrowing. Object types in TypeScript are *open* or *extendible* and not sealed or "exact" (as discussed in [microsoft/TypeScript#12936](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/12936)). Objects can always have more properties than are described in their types.  That means something like this could happen:

```
interface Foo {
  x: string;
  y: number;
}
const xformer = {
  y: (s: string) => +s,
  x: "oopsiedoodle" // <-- this is an excess property
}
csvToArray<Foo>("...", ["x", "y"], xformer); // no compiler error, but:
//  RUNTIME ERROR! keyToTransformerLookup[key] is not a function
```

It's probably unlikely, but you should know about it.  See [extend and only specify known properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69647392/2887218) for more information.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIBUD2CBOBDAdgZwGZNQFsJUAZJJAawFcwAeBAPigF4oBvAKCigG0YoAS0xRK8JLigIo6bFP4BdKBAAewCJgAmc7MFTCA5lAD8UTBABuJKAC5YCuwApuPKLv2YDANXQAbahB27oYuAJSszAiKANycAL6xnJjoxNhg6ADG0ACC2NgkwBycLrjUmBnAgkgiGdgWyNmoGCAMjM6uULUWQXqGADQuPGIg2HaNzXTDElKMAx3DyGhYeATEZBQ0YHZwiCgYOPhEJORUtK1zroIGmAQQAGKCqLqkwtBsuH75YXZRSlwdGWquigqCQAHc5GwugA6NK+QTARwAegAOphHMYWNDQkjQokOoJJI4rjdUPdHs9XuF-h0QeDsLCABaExF4wZQOLFDpk4DUVAiUEQ6GEdBgRyOQXhFjMGkAoGFCx+AKQulg2FgeGIpEYgCEKIAQgAiXgAPUNCgAVKE+rrTeaLYaDTiDGz2TxAThCoKAPIAIwAVhAKnYAEpBgiaOhYEB9GSYEDMNjsBJc2nDBmHACimUZ4uGseEmlUUplbtcHuBwU8Pn8bygitr2F4hdUClitMuROGQhECz2y0OaxOm2pZe54L9gYqvGGSjYfaWB1Wxw2tF4Y7T8Bkcimkh2i32KyO61O9CYG54CkcVe8SogbI73IgvP57cfnI3PoDQeAM-gc7cXpqzvN8OjiV0Ox5PkBQnb8Km3KRQI5B8OVTYR1FQD4sigO4KCKDoVB6DwDCQkA7EwahCF9Eg305d15SgFRB2sJN2TIqBryIwwSygABqbALh4QioENCgwGwQQIE0ChNF8CBDSgJEkSgOgAFpVKgYBmTkQQ5CwZQVCyPIoDAUFIFQUAXDozo6gaJp0BaXCkDaQ1oTcw1Y14Q0VA8kSQHNWMmOXVA8UU5StN0oQ9N8XxwSk2NfWoYAbBcJSoEAXg3AFKdqAQwAVQAOQQABJABZTMoEzEMQ29EMdVEeADwHYLhzXWcorMJBCnQKBSnKSpqigYoP04XqKiqERdJ2CQGAM9QtDkJA4OANoXEoOwAAUzIKEAdljJAflCOxKHa3cpHwkFn2g0QeygJBYg-ZJUnSbCEHACAAHFqHQVBNDuMoxoGrgSn+-qalspBxgc1p2nLOouM8QT6pGMZ7JaU6mERhdD2Yk9Nm2Br+yXY8WrPWZ2RJW4HieYAXnMVges+CBvnkP52QrL16XpmE4QRZE0QxLEcQgzsOIpskqcpcxR0g+kmRZRwUJ4D8nxfGChRFMUJXBHjZXLBiG2VenBXVTVkV1A1jTNS1rVtK2HSdJEXXxWl2dVScf1DcMfqjeNY2jRMOBTMt02hLMczzeACy0YsInOjtXZvGsAnpg2ICbFsVDbDdCVF7AptwRx8yRxqiaHVcwFCaXHx4L8p1-Nr5wJxcjzL08-xAK9E7vRXHyg18N2V3vYLr9uAK72skKV4WVau2ufwQhAkPA2ihqAA)