# Why is TypeScript reporting error in the wrong place when inferring inner type?

Tags: typescript

I have a quite complex problem which is hard to phrase in a concise title, sorry for that.
I crafted a function accepting a generic params type and returning a result type that is constructed from the params type. It involves string literals to describe the properties on the resulting type.
The idea is, that the IDE can provide suggestions and autocomplete when crafting the params type (variable). That works as expected.
But now I noticed, that typos in the non-generic properties of the params type are not detected by typescript anymore and instead weird errors are reported on the correct usage of the generic parts. Looks like the inference engine is doing something strange.

The idea behind the complex generic type was a good user experience, but now that simple typos in standard properties lead to hard to understand error messages, this benefit vanished.

Can someone explain the reason for this error or knows a way to fix it?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBA1AhjAllgIwBt0BeBAIjhAFs0Ys4BXGEChAH0odwDt2uFAO58AJgH0AzmhCj2AenkIQvJjRAM4uKLwRQAZgmiTJuYugBuOfOcnBQkWIj7UY+rAGN0ABRxYakgA8GMpg1LyikpjWhCQAfAgA3sAICESMuMyiIABcCKo0BBopaToA5plM2XkFRTAlVnixIJIA-HkYANoAusAAvqn24NDwCC4a7l4IACKMWMGh4ZHRTeYJyala6pJw-hA1anUNMbZ5nRjdiyrLnbwgFhqXrfn3Ggh5AEogHrCiwQA0+UOGji-SGjlGWEkyF4HgQ+iYsK0OnhIDgHgAFrNdgtwEsothViQEOQ7g8YHEABQQPwBPK+BgBYJxACUSRKigQADkoNQ8rhDEJ0KwaFAHkgMehsu4mERECg0C9yYC4BisLpwHtiQBmBBCWAAayiUNCaA81FEgIITEQmroxIATPCsLgiHZUpydkwCGN7bQVLtkbxAVDJGp0D8YKxzbIEKI5mMovo0ZjY+rRAhQ7RzKISqxmDBdIkBibEQbeFAhLoTdj5hhQX17JyAKJgLXoACMwB+vB2oXbHZJmaELsQyfRWLmlI2aQyWVyCAALABOAB0Hf+JSI5Uq1QQHY7q4ArJvUo0bCRJGcAOQ8XjXy6c3DZLAISWsRMSxgIACS02bCAeOqmY2lAPx+tQ8hhmUZQtIgVhEM+CAIUwLTwrAKwXiA-Qst2OiSFAJCrtuZSUnaEAkIe57NJIq53mynLxrsq7UbYb4mq+AAGd6cUYMBQPQKAIEUQFMJI6BCggrAAI6oTssaZMAnIAAJwJIAC0wzfHAmlRrAeG9oRIDEVApHkZRLEnJeq7UHQGiMCwIAMUoTFYJZRJoaIUBoRWiBquKXE8XxAkaEJIlYGJElSs+96IDJcnOHATZKK27YIA6Bl9uZIBOuQWAjpkqITrW05bnOVQLiu66nqUvAVPOeQHseOFKUoqkaVp5q6fx9Q9gRREkWRbZ+g67lYbR9EIJyrGXp+BhIKg6Bkm8lIiKqUA2pmvDIMFgm4C0bLhZFerRaIsVSSAslwVtO0zdhrUIKlfoILqD0AIoJdovB5Kq6D6IR24iHV-bPT2ux8MaC3QGMugUNudW7hQgIPdaiAACqLQAyh4eAQM4UTgRRLq8HwZSZgQG2ILexPXggOx4MDvmZiYuBlLwzRIFASoaKuCCZbaw0USAup5QVY4ppOuylak6RaA1S5rhuW47lkjWHieU1KAqXPviAgKSBiG1EBmRQINe8P1RV15WptGNoNjuNji6bp6Lov3oUQgOk7toXIICQgYrgmKfpG0ZJWeVktDed4PjhQA)

Simplified Type

```js
export type Variable = "temperature" | "rain" | "wind_speed" 

export interface Params<V extends Variable> {
  latitude: number
  longitude: number
  variables?: V[]
}  

export interface Data<V extends Variable> {
  timestamp: number
  variables: [V] extends [never] ? never : Record<V, number>
}

export async function fetchData<V extends Variable = never>(params: Params<V>) {
  return {} as unknown as Data<V> // stub implementation
}
```

Now this reports an error on 'rain' with 'string not assignable to never' instead
of showing that `longitud` should be spelled `longitude`.

```js
const example3 = await fetchData({
  latitude: 49.1,
  longitud: 11.5, // typo here, should be 'longitude'
  variables: ['rain'] // but typescript reports the error on 'rain'
})
```

Comment: Do you want to know why `'rain'` reports an error or why the typo does not show an error first?

Comment: It's not in "the wrong place" according to your type definition.  Inference fails, `V` defaults to `never`, and then the input fails to be a `Params<never>` for two reasons; both `variables` and `longitude` are incorrect. The compiler picks one to complain about.  If you really need to dictate how TS behaves here, you might want to make `fetchData()` generic in its entire input and then calculate `V` from it... perhaps as [this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/WKXyDw) shows.  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz Your playground link is a great answer to my question, as it solves the problem. I still don't get why the longitud typo is not shown first.

Comment: Do you agree that the input value is not a valid `Params<never>`?  If you're wondering why it defaults to `never` instead of `"rain"`, it's because the input is invalid and inference just fails. You told it to default to `never` in that situation, so that's what it does. Or are you wondering why it chose to complain about one prop instead of the other one? That's not really something we have control over; when two things are wrong, the compiler is free to choose one to complain about. I'm happy to write up an answer but can you tell me what the disconnect is?

Comment: Yes, I think I got it now. Because `longitude` is missing, type inference for `V` is not tried, and then it defaults to `never`. The compiler has now two errors, but displays only the one for the last prop. That was unexpected for me. 
Thx for your solution, it also works in my real use case [@atombrenner/openmeteo](https://github.com/atombrenner/openmeteo) and actually simplified my solution (on first sight I feared it would get even more complex).
I did not know about local types, now I have a new tool in my toolbox :-)  
because I could get rid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you call

```
const example3 = await fetchData({
  latitude: 49.1,
  longitud: 11.5, 
  variables: ['rain'] // error
})
```

the input object is of the wrong type, specifically because `longitude` is missing.  Therefore the compiler cannot properly infer the `V` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type argument, and it falls back to the [default](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-2-3.html#generic-parameter-defaults) `never` type. So now the compiler is checking against `Params<never>`.  The input fails to be a `Params<never>` in two ways.  One is that `longitude` is missing, and the other is that `variables` is not of type `never[]`.  Note that the `longitud` property is not really a type error; you would expect to see a compiler warning there due to [excess property checking](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks), but it's not the primary problem. Excess properties are generally allowed, see [extend and only specify known properties?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69647392/2887218) for more information.

So the compiler has two problems with your input, and it has to choose one to complain about.  It happens to choose the `variables` property.  That isn't what you wanted to see, but it's the compiler's prerogative how to prioritize errors.

---

That's why it's happening. If you want to change it, my suggestion is to make the `fetchData()` generic in the type `P` of the `params` input, and then use that `P` to *compute* `V`.  This will prevent any weird `never` inference from happening until *after* `params`'s type is inferred.  Like this:

```
export async function fetchData<P extends Params<Variable>>(params: P) {
  type V = P extends {variables: (infer V extends Variable)[]} ? V : never
  return {} as unknown as Data<V>
}
```

I used a function-local `type` alias for `V` but you could do it inline also.  Note how `V` becomes `never` if `variables` is missing from `P`.  But while `P` affects `V`, the reverse is not true; no matter what `V` turns out to be, `P` will be unaffected, so you don't get weird fallback behavior expecting `never[]` for `variables`.

---

Let's test it:

```
const example1 = await fetchData({
  latitude: 49.1,
  longitude: 11.5,
  variables: ["rain"]
})
console.log(example1.variables.rain) // okay
console.log(example1.variables.temperature) // error

const example2 = await fetchData({
  latitude: 49.1,
  longitude: 11.5
})
console.log(example2.variables.rain) // error

const example3 = await fetchData({
  latitude: 49.1,
  longitud: 11.5, // error, excess property
  variables: ['rain']
})
```

Looks like the behavior you wanted.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=5.3.3#code/FAUwHgDg9gTgLgAjgTwiBA1AhjAllgIwBt0BeBAIjhAFs0Ys4BXGEChAH0odwDt2uFAO58AJgH0AzmhCj2AenkIQvJjRAM4uKLwRQAZgmiTJuYugBuOfOcnBQkWIj7UY+rAGN0ABRxYakgA8GMpg1LyikpjWhCQAfAgA3sAICESMuMyiIABcCKo0BBopaToA5plM2XkFRTAlVnixIJIA-HkYANoAusAAvvb24NDwCC4a7l4IACKMWMGh4ZHRTeYJyala6pJw-hA1anUNMbZ5nRjdiyrLnbwgFhqXrfn3Ggh5AEogHrCiwQA0+UOGji-SGjlGWEkyF4HgQ+iYsK0OnhIDgHgAFrNdoFvFcIlFfAwAsETvE4gAKCB+AJ5bwASiSJRQaEwCHIePASyiiQQjRsJEkeQpfH0bxCXOuUWwqxI9J6CD6CGeIRqr3qqVYzBgukSSqhCERAGteFAhLoDdj5hhQQNgD9eDtQnsSABGdkILBCLCZVHorFzCkbNIZLK5BAAFgAnAA6V3-EpEcqVaoIV2umMAVgTqX5zSFCE6FB4-F6fXp9p0kigJBjSbKFPALpAGbzthjJcZij0RqwyErjprIDrUAbTbobpjbcFMeodA0jBYIC7Sg0MFg9gdTvHEBIACYPV6fYgxf6rUHE6GquHo3Gc6VeBUw3l01n+hWt0OR2OwM291OyRaDsfV4FdlBgdd6gHbdfwnEAAGZD29X1T0xc9g3SLRn0jWN40TZMshfDNswQbs11gQFwC8EwjHXegUGOWUWjOAByEsWLLekgA)